# sql query to find fifth record

Tags: sql

How can i find the fifth record in a table using sql query?

Comment: Why would you need something like that? Sounds like you are doing something wrong - how a record is stored in a table should not be the basis of a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Table T ORDER BY Column ASC) ORDER BY Column Desc
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are feeling argumentative, consider using "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1" and arguing that since SQL does not promise to return results in any particular order, the row returned is spiritually equivalent to the fifth, then show your tattoo: "The nth element of an unordered set is meaningless!"

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SqlServer you could use the `TOP` keyword to achieve this.

```
select top 1 * from(
select top 5 * from myTable order by orderingColumn) as A
order by orderingColumn desc
```

If you are using Oracle this should work (however i am not able to test this now)

```
select *
  from (
    select *, row_number() over (order by orderingColumn) r
      from items
  )
where r = 5;
```

Comment: I edited because i left the field name i used for test (utente) instead of "orderingColumn". I think now should be clearer. The subquery retrieves the first 5 rows ordered by the desired column (our desired row is the last one in this set) and then reverse the ordering of this subset and take the first row, which is the one we are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4;`

Answer (score 1):

Fifth record **only** in **MySQL**

`SELECT * FROM anytable LIMIT ORDER BY id LIMIT 4,1`

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server (recent-ish incarnations, anyway) something like this should work:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      *, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY the_table.the_column) 'row_num'
    FROM 
      the_table
  ) numbered_rows
WHERE
  row_num = 5
```

However, I'd actually put my vote with Thomas L Holaday's answer :)